# How to extract all the numbers from a text file using re.findall() and compute the sum using a for-loop?

Tags: python

The basic outline of this problem is to read the file, look for integers using the `re.findall()`, looking for regular expression of `[0-9]+` and then converting the extracted strings to integers and summing up the integers. I'm having different outcome it supposed to end with (209). Also, how can I simplify my code? Thanks (here is the txt file http://py4e-data.dr-chuck.net/regex_sum_167791.txt)

```
import re
hand = open("regex_sum_167791.txt")
total = 0
count = 0
for line in hand:
   count = count+1
   line = line.rstrip()
   x =  re.findall("[0-9]+", line) 
   if len(x)!= 1 : continue
   num = int(x[0])
   total = num + total
print(total)
```

Comment: What is the purpose of `count`?

Comment: Additionally, what is the purpose of `if len(x)!= 1 : continue`? I don't see in the specification to only sum at most one integer per line.

Comment: And why `num = int(x[0])`? What if there are multiple `int`s in a single line?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you need to sum all the numbers in your txt:

```
total = 0
with open("regex_sum_167791.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        total += sum(map(int, re.findall("\d+", line)))
print(total)
# 417209
```

**Logics**

To start with, try using `with` when you do `open` so that once any job is done, `open` is closed.

Following lines are removed as they seemed redundant:

- `count = count+1`: Not used.
- `line = line.rstrip()`: `re.findall` takes care of extraction, so you don't have to worry about stripping lines.
- `if len(x)!= 1 : continue`: Seems like you wanted to skip the line with no digits. But since `sum(map(int, re.findall("\d+", line)))` returns zero in such case, this is also unnecessary.
- `num = int(x[0])`: Finally, this effectively grabs only one digit from the line. In case of two or more digits found in a single line, this won't serve the original purpose. And since `int` cannot be directly applied to iterables, I used `map(int, ...)`.

Answer (score 0):

You were almost there:

```
import re
hand = open("regex_sum_167791.txt")
total = 0

for line in hand:
    count = count+1
    line = line.rstrip()

    x =  re.findall("[0-9]+", line) 

    for i in x:
        total += int(i)

print(total)
```

Answer: 417209

Answer (score 0):

I believe the question asks to compute the average: [image]

Either ways, its a very similar program in the end:

```
import re


file_name = input('Enter file: ')
if len(file_name) < 1:
    file_name = 'mbox-short.txt'
try:
    file_handle = open(file_name)
except:
    print('Invalid File')
    quit()

new_revision_list = list()
total = 0
for line in file_handle:
    words = line.rstrip()
    # regex
    x = re.findall('^New Revision:.([0-9]+)', words)
    # skip the lines that don't contain what we need
    if len(x) < 1:
        continue
    # convert the list of the string to an int
    x = int(x[0])
    # append x to the list of integers
    new_revision_list.append(x)
    # add the value to the total, in order to calculate the average
    total += x

print(total / len(new_revision_list))
```